# How did the Portuguese language end up being spoken in several African countries?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

I can understand how Brazil ended up being a Portuguese speaking country, but how about Africa? How did that happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no mistery. Just as Brazil was a Portuguese colony for more than three centuries, several African and Asian countries were Portuguese colonies as well. Wherever the Portuguese presence was long enough, most of those countries adopted the Portuguese language as their official language.

> - Portuguese (português or, in full, língua portuguesa) is a Romance language and the sole official language of Angola, Brazil, Cape Verde, Guinea-Bissau, Mozambique, Portugal, and São Tomé and Príncipe. It also has co-official language status in East Timor, Equatorial Guinea and Macau. As the result of expansion during colonial times, a cultural presence of Portuguese and Portuguese creole speakers are also found in Goa, Daman and Diu in India; in Batticaloa on the east coast of Sri Lanka; in the Indonesian island of Flores; and in Malacca in Malaysia.   read more at [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_language)